# Python Reading from JSON accented characters coming out wrong

Tags: python, json, decoding, diacritics

I have a string like this (`"Theres loads of adventures to be had here;\nYou'll get your own Kobémon\nand get to catch more!"`) in my .JSON file and when I read from it into the python file and into a Tkinter textbox I get `"Ã©"` instead of `é`. Is there a way to stop this. Im reading the .JSON using this :`(self.Lines = json.load(open("Data/Lines.json")))`

Comment: Have you tried adding the param `encoding='utf-8'` when loading the json?

Comment: @Idlehands Just tried that; Doesnt work still get the same characters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try This:

`(self.Lines = json.load(open("Data/Lines.json","rb"), encoding="utf-8"))`

The difference is loading the file in bytes and reading it in `utf-8` format (assuming that's the file format).

Comment: Ahhh! Thanks a lot. Appreciate it.